# Is it possible to access App instance from react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have custom component in my reactjs application:

```
class Word extends React.Component {
    click() {
       // can i access app instance here?
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain what you need access to? maybe theres another way of accomplishing what you need.

Comment: I have socketio instance there.

Comment: Show us your complete code for your component instead.

Comment: Components only have access to the props passed to them from their parent. If you want something from a higher level component to reach a child component, pass it down as a prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not precise but I am assuming you have top level App component which has child components and you are asking if child component can access App component.

If thats the case then just pass reference to it as a prop:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        <Word parent={this} />
    }
}

class Word extends React.Component {
    click() {
       console.log(props.parent);
    }
}
```

However I believe this to be anti-pattern.

Comment: If you believe it to be anti-pattern I'd love to see the alternative, or if none is needed, what the alternative overall solution is (NB: I hold no belief whatsoever, I'm just curious about an issue which also arose a while ago [with KnockoutJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946789/best-practice-with-multiple-viewmodels/27947889#27947889)).

Comment: There are many reasons why this is wrong, for example it makes components more coupled, which makes them harder to test. In React you should pass all the required data down as props, there is no need for child component to know about its parent. An alternative is to Lift State Up (more in React Docs).